# laravel partial breaks rest of the flowe

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm working on my first laravel app and though I get a lot of the basics, the partial view part eludes me.

My laravel is 5.6.* and I'm trying to loop over a collection.
Dumped, the collection counts to 2 entries. Neither @each nor @include would let the rest of the page show.

Now code :

```
@section('content')

 // This each loop output only one element and then nothing else happens.
    @each('book.item', $collection, 'item')

    // If I disable the each, the include would work, but...
    @include('book.item')

    <p>
        All that's after won't work
    </p>


@endsection
```

I do not have any error displayed, no clue nor leads and can't find a proper way to search it on the web, previous tries yielded nothing.

Many thanks to any help,

### Updated details

Data is dumped and counts 2 entries, its is passed through controller as follows

```
$books = Book::all();
return view('book/index', [
    'collection' => $books
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you send data to view like this,

```
$users = User::paginate(10);
return view('users', ['users' => $users]);
```

And you add code like this for showing on blade,

```
@foreach($users as $user)
     {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
{{ $users->links() }}
```

You can check this package for example laravel project for get users and show on users blade with pagination

https://github.com/durmus-aydogdu/laravel-pagination

Comment: The @foreach does work but including doesn't, again. The problem is specifically on including and using partials. Thank you for answering btw :).

Comment: Problem might be related about passing data to include blade, please check link for example usage,
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8502

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it ( big shame ).

My partial had @section('content') and @endsection tags.

To other noobs this replaces the code in the content section of your page's template.